# UnityEngine 4.5.5f Can't get file version info

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, fileversioninfo

I'm trying to get the fileversion using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo(v=vs.110).aspx

and also process.MainModule.FileVersionInfo but both of them return an empty string.

If I try It with a simple Console program, It works. Is there something in Unity 4.5 that It can't get It? Is there any alternative?

Comment: If i remember right, Unity's Mono compiler does not copy `AssemblyVersion` into `System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo`, the Microsoft .net compiler does.

Comment: >.< Is there anything else I could use?